# INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES gives empty sting even after target_include_directories

Tags: cmake

I am having the problem printing the variable like `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`,      I would show the simple `CMakeLists.txt` that I write:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Library)

add_library(hello src/hello.cpp)
target_include_directories(hello PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

message(STATUS "The interface_include_directories : ${INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}")
```

As shown above,  `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include` should be in the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` after `target_include_directories`,
However, it prints an empty string instead.

I would like to know if there is anyway to print the include path that is related to specific library ,`hello` for example  in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include should be in the INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES after target_include_directories

It should be in a `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` *target property*, not in a variable.

> if there is anyway to print the include path that is related to specific library ,hello for example in this case.

```
get_target_property(var hello INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message(STATUS "${var}")
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to print all the include path in cmake( including c++ standard ones) ?

Comment: eerrmm, what for? You have to find all variables with include paths and print them. You can compile in verbose to see what is passed to compiler. `c++ standard ones` there are no "standard ones", C++ standard does not mention any include paths. There are system specific, in case consult your operating system documentation (FHS and POSIX on linux), there are compiler specific include paths, in case consult compiler documentation (compile code with `gcc -v` on GCC to see what it includes).

Comment: Because after using target_link_directories for marking library named hello with PUBLIC mode, in another folder, there is main.cpp uses this hello library ,when include the header file for hello library, I get to write #include<hello.h> instead of #include “hello.h” which I don’t understand. As far as I know the brackets one means it would search the path that is predefined by system or compiler, So I would like to know ,does target_link_directories makes some difference?

Comment: `which I don’t understand` I can only recommend a tutor or to read [some books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). `does target_link_directories makes some difference?` No, `target_link_directories` does not affect compiler include search paths, it adds a path to library search paths. `target_include_directories` adds a path to compiler include search paths, which affects both `#include <hello.h>` and `#include "hello.h"`.